# nodejs emailjs connect econnrefused, smtp

Tags: node.js, gmail, port, email

my node server starts fine, is running fine until i'm trying to send an email with emailjs...
this exception is thrown:

```
error :  code 5
error :  previous { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
error :  smtp undefined
```

my code:

```
var ES = require('./email-settings');
var EM = {};
module.exports = EM;

EM.server = require("emailjs/email").server.connect({
    host        : ES.host,
    user        : ES.user,
    password    : ES.password,
    ssl         : true,
    port        : 465
});

EM.dispatchResetPasswordLink = function(account, callback)
{
    EM.server.send({
        from         : ES.sender,
        to           : account.email,
        subject      : 'Password Reset',
        text         : 'something went wrong... :(',
        attachment   : EM.composeEmail(account)
    }, callback );
}
```

in email-settings i define host, user, password... they are not undefined. my smtp-server is gmail. do i have to define any other settings? maybe for my gmail-account? is emailjs using port 80 or so? my app is running on 8003

im looking for a solution for quite a long time now... thx for help :)

Comment: can you give us the code, where you define host, user and password. Maybe here lies the bug. It should follow this syntax:           **user:    "testaccount@gmail.com",
 password:"testpassword",
 host:    "smtp.gmail.com",
 ssl:     true**

Comment: hey michael, thx for your reply.
here is my code in email-settings
`module.exports = {
 host  : 'smtp.gmail.com',
 user   : 'myemail@gmail.com',
 password  : 'secret',
 sender  : 'firstname lastname <myemail@gmail.com>'
}`

Comment: yes these definitions seem alright. Gmail is very restrictive whith this smtp stuff lately. Maybe this is the reason. Log in to your account and reload your browser several times when sending the message. You should see a little pop up bar on the top then in your gmail account where they ask you if you know about the smtp or if it is a hacker. Maybe they will even ask you for a telephone verification.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, have you had any luck with this David?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unlock captcha code in gmail. As below link

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha

Comment: Please elaborate more your answer